# Expand Rows : Generate Rows until next change

Tags: sql, hana

I need help in coming up with the SQL for the below issue ..I need to generate the rows one per month until i see the next change

For Ex

```
ID Price MMYYYY
1  $20  012016
1  $25  082016
1  $30  052017
2  $21  052016
2  $26  112016
```

The result data should be something like this

```
ID Price MMYYYY
1  $20  012016
1  $20  022016
1  $20  032016
1  $20  042016
1  $20  052016
1  $20  062016
1  $20  072016
1  $25  082016
1  $25  092016
1  $25  102016
1  $25  112016
1  $25  122016
1  $25  012017
1  $25  022017
1  $25  032017
1  $25  042017
1  $30  052017
2  $21  052016
2  $21  062016
2  $21  072016
2  $21  082016
2  $21  092016
2  $21  102016
2  $26  112016
```

Basically i have duplicate the record until i see the next change ..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wish I could help you. This is easily done in SQL, but I know absolutely nothing about HANA. Good luck.

Comment: Most of SQL Commands work in HANA...Let me know how you go about this using SQL..I will try implementing the same in HANA as well

Answer (score 0):

Should work in almost any SQL db:

A simple approach is to just use a CROSS JOIN of the years X months that you need. then LFT JOIN your data (or query) to that list. e.g.

```
select concat(m,y) as MMYYYY
from (
    select 2016 as y union all
    select 2017
      ) Years 
cross join (
    select '01' as m union all
    select '02' as m union all
    select '03' as m union all
    select '04' as m union all
    select '05' as m union all
    select '06' as m union all
    select '07' as m union all
    select '08' as m union all
    select '09' as m union all
    select '10' as m union all
    select '11' as m union all
    select '12' as m
      ) Months
LEFT JOIN (
    your-data-here
    ) d ON concat(m,y) = d.mmyyyy
```

**Simply add/remove years as you need them.**

If your version of Hana does support CTEs you could use it "upside down" like so:

```
with Years as (
    select 2016 as y union all
    select 2017
    )
, Months as (
    select '01' as m union all
    select '02' as m union all
    select '03' as m union all
    select '04' as m union all
    select '05' as m union all
    select '06' as m union all
    select '07' as m union all
    select '08' as m union all
    select '09' as m union all
    select '10' as m union all
    select '11' as m union all
    select '12' as m
    )
select concat(m,y) as MMYYYY
from Years 
cross join Months
LEFT JOIN (
    your-data-here
    ) d ON concat(m,y) = d.mmyyyy
```

OR you could use a "recursive cte" (common table expression) but I think that is overkill here.

Comment: this will not replicate price in missing months

Answer (score 0):

Here is some addons to Used_By_Already's query

```
with cte as
(
select
    data.ID,
    data.rn,
    p.Price,
    data.mmyyyy,
    ifnull(p.Price,0) price2,
    case when p.Price is null then 0 else 1 end as pno

from (
----------
select
    *
from (

select
    row_number() over (order by yyyy, mm) rn,
    yyyy,
    mm,
    concat(mm,yyyy) mmyyyy
from (
    select 2016 as yyyy from dummy
    union all
    select 2017 from dummy
      ) Years 
cross join (
    select '01' as mm from dummy union all
    select '02' as mm from dummy union all
    select '03' as mm from dummy union all
    select '04' as mm from dummy union all
    select '05' as mm from dummy union all
    select '06' as mm from dummy union all
    select '07' as mm from dummy union all
    select '08' as mm from dummy union all
    select '09' as mm from dummy union all
    select '10' as mm from dummy union all
    select '11' as mm from dummy union all
    select '12' as mm from dummy 
      ) Months

) as d
cross join (
    select distinct ID from Prices
) as products
order by ID, rn
----------

) as data
left join Prices as p
    on data.ID = p.ID and
       data.mmyyyy = p.mmyyyy
order by data.ID, rn
)
select
    ID,
    rn,
    mmyyyy,
    max(Price) over (partition by ID, partitionno) as Price
from (
    select
        ID, rn, mmyyyy, Price,
        ( select sum(c.pno) from cte as c where c.ID = cte.ID and c.rn <= cte.rn ) as partitionno
    from cte
) t
```

I used [SQL Row_Number() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-row_number-over-partition-by-order-by.aspx) for ordering results and also MAX() aggregate function with partition by clause in the above [SQL CTE query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18)
I used the CTE expression in SQL query just like subselect statements and temporary tables to query for more than once in a single script block

part of the output of the above SQL query execution is as follows

[image]

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To replicate the rows on all following months until next valid try this:

```
WITH
x as (-- extract month and year in numeric format
    select *, cast(substring(MMYYYY,1,2) as INTEGER) m, cast(substring(MMYYYY,3,4) as INTEGER) y
    from YourTable
),
m as (-- prepare numbers 1..12 (list of monts)
    select top 12 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by OBJECT_OID) m
    from sys.OBJECTS
),
y as (-- expand years needed for each id
    select distinct id, m.m, y
    from x, m
)
-- let's do the trick
select x.ID, x.Price, right('0'+cast(y.m as varchar(2)),2)+cast(y.y as varchar(4)) MMYYYY
from y
inner join x on 
    -- same ID
    y.ID = x.ID and (
    -- match all rows from this one..
    (x.y*100+x.m <= y.y*100+y.m) 
    and not exists (
        -- until not exists a following valid row
        select 1 
        from x xx 
        -- same id
        where y.ID = xx.ID
        -- following this one
        and (xx.y*100+xx.m > x.y*100+x.m) 
        -- but preceding the current row
        and (xx.y*100+xx.m <= y.y*100+y.m))
    )
order by y.id, y.y, y.m
```

output

```
ID  Price   MMYYYY
1   $20     012016
1   $20     022016
1   $20     032016
1   $20     042016
1   $20     052016
1   $20     062016
1   $20     072016
1   $25     082016
1   $25     092016
1   $25     102016
1   $25     112016
1   $25     122016
1   $25     012017
1   $25     022017
1   $25     032017
1   $25     042017
1   $30     052017
1   $30     062017
1   $30     072017
1   $30     082017
1   $30     092017
1   $30     102017
1   $30     112017
1   $30     122017
2   $21     052016
2   $21     062016
2   $21     072016
2   $21     082016
2   $21     092016
2   $21     102016
2   $26     112016
2   $26     122016
```